# Synchronizing data, want to track what has changed

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

I have a program query data from database (MySQL) every minute.

```
while 1:
    self.alerteng.updateAndAnalyze()
    time.sleep(60)
```

but the data doesn't change frequently; maybe once an hour or a day.(change by another C++ program)

I think the best way is track the change if a change happens then I query and update my data.

any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you're doing, but SQLAlchemy's Events functionality might help you out.

It lets you run code whenever something happens in your database, i.e. after you insert a new row, or set a column value. I've used it in Flask apps to kick off notifications or other async processes.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/events.html#mapper-events

Here's toy code from a Flask app that'll run the kick_off_analysis() function whenever a new YourModel model is created in the database.

```
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(YourModel, "after_insert")
def kick_off_analysis(mapper, connection, your_model):
  # do stuff here
```

Hope that helps you get started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how expensive `updateAndAnalyze()` is, but I'm pretty sure it's like most SQL commands: not something you really want to poll.

You have a textbook case for the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).  You want MySQL to call something somehow in your code whenever it gets updated.  I'm not positive of the *exact* mechanism to do this, but there should be way to set a trigger on your relevant tables where it can notify your code that the underlying table has been updated.  Then, instead of polling, you basically get "interrupted" with knowledge that you need to do something.  It will also eliminate that up-to-a-minute lag you're introducing, which will make whatever you're doing feel more snappy.